# Sequelize insert with max()+1

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Given a Sequelize `model`, how can I insert a record in the database with one of the columns being `MAX(column)+1`, without using sequences?

Another way to phrase the same question:

What is a more elegant way to write the following code?

```
const newOrder = yield model.max('order') + 1
const newProduct = yield model.create({ name: 'car', order: newOrder })
```

I cannot predict how the `order` will be changed later (so sequences can't help) and this looks like a race condition waiting to happen. There must be a better way to write this.

Comment: @VivekDoshi Correct. That is what I want to achieve. If I insert order 25 and order 25 is later deleted, then the next insert should also be 25.

Comment: If record 24 is deleted and 25 exists, then the next one would be 26. No problem. If both 24 and 25 are deleted, then the next one would be 24.